# Paypal Subscription : Adjustment of the amount on revised plan

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

In the paypal subscription, we have integrated the revised subscription feature for our system.

Subscription flow working fine, but when the user upgrade or downgrade their plans in mid of the subscription cycle, do we have any option to adjust their subscription amount?

Example :
Customer has purchased the **Plan A with price $100 for 1 month recurring plan**.
After 15 days, customer is upgrading to the **Plan B with price $500**

In that case currently no extra charge is executed by the Paypal for that 15 days, From the next payment cycle paypal will charge $500, **So how can we manage that 15 days extra charge for that upgraded plan?**

For the upgrade we want to manage refund for the adjustment amount and for the upgrade we want to charge extra adjustment amount.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Shanky
Posted answer take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did solution as below, if anyone need help for the case.

If customer purchase Plan A with price $100 and upgrade subscription to Plan B After 15 days.

So, customer used plan for 15 days and remaining 15 days amount will be return
Before moved to next plan. Previous plan's subscription will be cancel and calculated amount will be refund.

Calculation:
Charged amount = (price * plan used days) / duration (In Days)

Charged amount = ($100 * 15) / 30

Charged amount = $50

Refundable amount = Price - Charged amount

Refundable amount = $100 - $10

Refundable amount = $50

Simply we are giving refund before starting new plan and generating new subscription with new amount.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new plan with a 1 month trial period for the prorated/adjusted amount you want to bill next, and a regular period for the amount you want to bill ongoing. Use this plan to revise the subscription.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
This will works for the upgrade flow but there is any option for the downgrade to adjust amount or refund amount?